# How can I add data structures to dynamic link libraries in c++

Tags: c++, dll, struct, linker, libraries

I'm working on a DLL for some graphics apps, and i want to add some data structures in it, how should i go about it? I need to be able to use these structures within the library functions and to be able to use that datatype in an app that uses the library.

Comment: `#define VECTOR ( struct vector_3D){float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}` is that even valid preprocessor macro?

Comment: it worked in a different instance when i was building a header for a specific executable, it worked then, but idk what to do here to link it properly, if you know a better way to do it then by all means, i'm simply trying to add a variable type to the library, this is what i came up with...

Comment: @Creris: Yes, the macro definition is valid, the space just after `VECTOR` makes it a parameterless macro that just expands to that bunch of code. However, that code does not make too much sense...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing namespaces and classes. In your CPP you should write:

```
namespace RE_Math
{
    float REM_Funcs::vector_length(vector_3D v)
    {
        return sqrt((v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z));
    }
}
```

and so on...

BTW, you should be more precise with the language when talking about programming languages: you are defining a class with some member functions, not constant structs...

Comment: that so barely breezes the surface of the iceberg I'm not even going to consider the heap of other issues with his question. Not to mention the EPIC question title.

Comment: well sry for the bad question, i'm a bit tired and want to finish up as quickly as possible with the first part, i'm on a tight schesule, but thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @sehe: Yeah, you are right, I think there may be some difficulties with the English language, in addition to the C++ one. I'm not a native English speaker so I sympathize. Anyway, my interpretation is that the question is probably directed towards this particular issue.

Comment: @TheReapersHound I just wonder what lead you to even type const struct when you are asing about C++

Comment: @TheReapersHound: The think is that it looks like you are copying & pasting a lot of code without really knowing what you are doing, or understanding the basic syntax of the language. Even if you make it to compile it will probably not do what you think it does.

Comment: Sadly I'm not convinced the language barrier has a signicant impact here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: ok, i want to make a DLL in C++ and i want to have a few custom variable types(structs) along with the functions so that when i can use them in apps